# store date type data into database while user django

Tags: python, django

i cannot store the date into database. When I use debug, there is:

```
cleaned data = {'nick_name': 'Leren', 'gender': 'male', 'birday': None, 'address': '617 bridge', 'mobile': '2263408858'}

data = <QueryDict: {'nick_name': ['Leren'], 'birthday': ['2018-04-04'], 'gender': ['male'], 'address': ['617 bridge'], 'mobile': ['2263408858'], 'email': ['1@qq.com'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['1bzcpBzTOra7yTFBiwXc9sPLw8V6ETf7ciCDNqt1Jo9EtXZ4Q1qVBCIEWVVwPxGi']}>
```

i do not know why the birday does not exist in cleaned data but it exist in the data.
And how can i store it into my database?

html file:

```
<form class="perinform" id="jsEditUserForm" autocomplete="off">
                    <ul class="right">
                        <li>nickname：
                           <input type="text" name="nick_name" id="nick_name" value="{{ request.user.nick_name|default_if_none:'' }}" maxlength="10">
                            <i class="error-tips"></i>
                        </li>
                        <li>birthday：
                           <input type="text" id="birth_day" name="birthday" value="{{ request.user.birday|date:'Y-m-d H:i:s' }}"  />
                            <i class="error-tips"></i>
                        </li>
                        <li>gender：
                            <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio"  name="gender" value="male" {% ifequal request.user.gender "male" %}checked="checked"{% endifequal %} >male</label>
                            <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" {% ifequal request.user.gender "female" %}checked="checked"{% endifequal %}>female</label>
                        </li>
                        <li class="p_infor_city">address：
                            <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="" value="{{ request.user.address|default_if_none:'' }}" maxlength="10">
                            <i class="error-tips"></i>
                        </li>
                        <li>phone                                <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="" value="{{ request.user.mobile|default_if_none:'' }}" maxlength="10">
                        </li>
                        <li>email：
                            <input class="borderno" type="text" name="email" readonly="readonly" value="{{ request.user.email }}"/>
                            <span class="green changeemai_btn">[edit]</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="button heibtn">
                            <input type="button" id="jsEditUserBtn" value="save">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                </form>
```

views.py:

```
class UserInfoView(LoginRequiredMixin,View):  #用户个人信息  所以必须登陆才可以访问
    def get(self,request):
        return  render(request,"usercenter-info.html",{
        })

    def post(self, request):
        # 不像用户咨询是一个新的。需要指明instance。不然无法修改，而是新增用户
        user_info_form = UserInfoForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if user_info_form.is_valid():
            user_info_form.save()
            return HttpResponse(
                '{"status":"success"}',
                content_type='application/json')
        else:
            # 通过json的dumps方法把字典转换为json字符串
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(
                    user_info_form.errors),
                content_type='application/json')
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    nick_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="nickname",default="")
    birday=models.DateField(verbose_name="birthday",null=True,blank=True)
    gender=models.CharField(choices=(("male","male"),("female","female")),default="",max_length=10)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="")
    mobile=models.CharField(max_length=11,null=True,blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to="image/%Y/%m",default="image/default.png",max_length=100) 
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="email",default="")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="user profile"  
        verbose_name_plural=verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

forms.py:

```
class UserInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile 
        fields = ['nick_name','gender','birday','address','mobile']
```

there are my code above. 
there might be something wrong when turning data into cleaned data

Comment: Can you please also share the code for `UserInfoForm`

Comment: Did you notice that you try to read `birday` while the attribute seems to be named bir**th**day?

Comment: you can have a look at models.py. attribute birday is correct

Comment: In HTML form you have given the name as `birthday` which should be `birday` (typo), hence clean_data doesnt recognize it.